# How to serve filetype object in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using the URLLib2 method to download a file from another server via a rest api (the url can't be exposed to the user--that's why it needs to be done on the backend).

It gives me the following response:

```
(<addinfourl at 4365818480 whose fp = <google.appengine.dist27.socket._fileobject object at 0x1043883d0>>
```

I'm now trying to find a way to serve this file to the end user (a download). I did quite a bit of research tonight but had no luck. I tried using print .read() and that didn't help either.

Here's some additional information:

The Platform is Google Appengine. And below is the relevant code:

In calltrunk.get_recording:

```
req = urllib2.Request(url, None, forward_headers)
print response[0].read()
stream = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

In my main.py

```
response = calltrunk.get_recording(ConversationId=cId)
print response[0].read()
```

Could really use a hand here!

Comment: Can you show the code that gives you this result? And how you serve it depends entirely on your web framework (Django? Pylons? Google app engine? Etc)

Comment: What response do you get when you call the read() method of this object?

Comment: Just updated the question with some additional details (the code) and the platform info (google appengine). I'm using Jinja2 overall, but wasn't going to for this specific part of the code if that makes sense.